# RegEx for matching spaces between a variable and commas

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse through a url string so I can validate it for testing. My string looks

```
p_videoid=119110,p_videoepnumber= 0,p_videoairdate=NOT NULL,videoseason=null
```

My problem is for some videos there is a space in p_videoepnumber= 0. I need to find the substring that starts with p_videoepnumber and ends with the comma, and then remove all spaces.

I want my final output to look like:

```
p_videoid=119110,p_videoepnumber=0,p_videoairdate=NOTNULL,videoseason=null
```

I can't just remove all spaces from the string because there are certain values that have a space.

Comment: would `string.replace("= ","=")` work?

Comment: Could you explain what spaces you **wouldn't** want to remove?

Comment: I would assume @BenjaminUrquhart comment would have to be what you're looking for based on how your question is worded.  If not, try to clarify the question so we can help you out.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart I think that works! I feel dumb for not thinking of that now lol. I don't want to remove spaces in places like p_videoairdate=NOT NULL.

Comment: @learningruby347 I've gone and added an answer

Comment: @learningruby347 Don't feel dumb. Keep going!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you said, you can simply do:

```java
string.replace("= ","=");
```

If you only want the `p_videoepnumber` key to be changed:

```java
string.replace("p_videoepnumber= ","p_videoepnumber=");
// Using regex:
string.replaceAll("(p_videoepnumber=)(\\s+)","$1");
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwFIX3PEUIDgnWYkaRDO61DtVJRa5tkGiahiQtSPHZa6jioIvTge@en3uFDmbX6jYMpQbv8RqU6ZFtz1qV2AcIUbpGVbiOB1oEp8xlf8TgLp7hHr1ANI4iMLGnTlUyBgTnC87nyRtIa9r6LJ3AHwTKVRCkyDdbnO@yLBmpl@AbI0yrNVkiVNx9kHXatCG1cSNoQ19jqZNWQykpiasJEYSx5T/un39i@Jv917XSmhL6nWX0cPBTFlsnfOx5oMcwPAE)

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/NoPM3E/1) might help you to do so. It simply creates a group in between two boundaries where the spaces might be:

```
p_videoepnumber=(\s+)[0-9]+,
```

- You can simply call those spaces with `$1` and replace it with an empty string `''`.
- You can also add additional boundaries to this expression, if you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, in this String :

```
p_videoid=119110,p_videoepnumber= 0,p_videoairdate=NOT NULL,videoseason=null
```

You want to catch `p_videoepnumber= 0,`.

The first idea that comes to mind is attempting to match `p_videoepnumber= .*,`, but it would actually capture `p_videoepnumber= 0,p_videoairdate=NOT NULL,`.

As you want to stop at the first comma, you will actually use a [reluctant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) matcher. You will actually match `p_videoepnumber= .*?,` (Notice the extra `?`).

From that point, here is the commented code :

```
String req = "p_videoid=119110,p_videoepnumber= 0,p_videoairdate=NOT NULL,videoseason=null";

// Add parenthesis to indicate the group to capture
String regex = "(p_videoepnumber= .*?,)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(req);

// find() finds the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
if (matcher.find()) {
    // Displays the number of found groups : 1
    System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
    // Displays the found group : p_videoepnumber= 0,
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    // Replace " " with "" in the first group and display the result : 
    // p_videoid=119110,p_videoepnumber=0,p_videoairdate=NOT NULL,videoseason=null
    System.out.println(matcher.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1).replaceAll(" ", "")));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.split` method:

```
String[] splitedString = "yourString".split(",");
```

and then you can iterate each element of your String array and find the element that start with `p_videoepnumber`

```
for(int i=0; i<splitedString.length; i++){
    if(splitedString[i].startsWith("p_videoepnumber"){
        splitedString[i] = splitedString[i].trim();
     }
}
String parsedString = String.join(",", splitedString);
```